# jQuery loading layout before adding change events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, promise

Basically I have two functions, `loadLayout` and `saveLayout`.

`loadLayout` needs to load first so that I can apply a `.change()` event to elements that it loads, so when they are changed `saveLayout` is fired.

I tried using `.then()` but I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadLayout()
        .then(function() {
            $('input, textarea').change(function(){
                saveLayout();
            });
        });
});

function loadLayout() {
    console.log('loading layout...');
    chrome.storage.sync.get('layout', function(data) {
        $('#sp_tools').html(data.layout);
        console.log('Loaded Layout: \n' + data.layout);
    });
}

function saveLayout() {
    console.log("saving layout...")

    let $content = $("#sp_tools");

    let $clone = $content.clone()
    $clone.find('input, textarea').each(function () {
        let $input = $(this);
        // start an attribute object later use with attr()
        let attrs = {
            value: $input.val()
        };

        if ($input.is('textarea')) {
            $input.html($input.val())
        }

        // add the attributes to element
        $input.attr(attrs);
    });

    let html = $clone.html();

    chrome.storage.sync.set({layout: html}, function () {
        console.log('Saved Layout: \n' + html);
    });
}
```

Comment: First, try whether `chrome.storage.sync.get()` returns a Promise. Just put `return` in front of it. If it doesn't, just create a promise that resolves in the success callback.

Comment: I would be surprised if that chrome function returned a Promise since it seems it's already taking a callback function as an argument, but who knows (edit: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea)

Comment: @Jeto You're probably right, the docs don't mention promises either.

Comment: Actually deleted my first comment as the proposed solution was wrong. Take a look at [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and you should find a way (edit: well, check the answer, now, I guess :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadLayout` needs to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Try the following.

```js
function loadLayout() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.storage.sync.get('layout', function(data) {
          $('#sp_tools').html(data.layout);
          resolve(data);
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Adhering to the principle of promisifying at the lowest level, you might like to consider :

```
chrome.storage.sync.getAsync = function(identifier) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            chrome.storage.sync.get(identifier, resolve);
        }
        catch(e) {
            reject(e); // will only propagate synchronous errors but better than nothing
        }
    });
};

function loadLayout() {
    chrome.storage.sync.getAsync('layout')
    .then(data => {
        $('#sp_tools').html(data.layout);
        return data; // or maybe `return data.layout`
    });
}
```

`chrome.storage.sync.getAsync()` is thus available for reuse elsewhere in your code base.

Answer (score -1):

```
An easy way to fix it would be to set a timeout like this:


$(document).ready(function(){
    loadLayout()
        .then(function() {
            $('input, textarea').change(function(){
                setTimeout(function{
saveLayout(); 1000})
            });
        });
});
```